# is it posible to upload multiple files using a text file that contains the path to all files to be uploaded?

Tags: php, javascript, file, upload, filepath

Is there any way to upload multiple files using a single file?...basically i want to upload multiple pdf files at once, using one single file that contains the path to each one of the pdf files...and store the information to mysql database...

PS: i dont want to merge all the files into 1 huge pdf...i want each 1 of pdf file to be uploaded to server dir at once and then store the file info to database eg. path, file info, filename for later use..

Answer (score 2):

In order for a file to be uploaded, the user has to select that file manually. It's a security measure (otherwise websites could examine arbitrary files on your computer without your knowledge, which would be bad).

Answer (score 0):

No - Because it would break the Javascript sandbox model (i.e. would be a security problem).

Answer (score 0):

For security concern, it's hard to do this by javascript, which means you will have the access to others local files.

Why not just pack them up into a zip file then unzip on the sever side?